# Library for Trust-Region Reflective algorithms in C

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to rebuild some Matlab code in C that uses their fsolve function.  From the documentation it's using a "trust region reflective" algorithm (I already built it using a Levenberg-marquardt algorithm and it's converging completely differently).  Can anyone recommend a library for doing this type of optimization in C/C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of general-purpose algorithms for which there is a **global convergence guarantee** (under standard assumptions, don't ask :) ). These methods are the line search and the trust region methods. If you wish, you can read more on this topic in the book of [Nocedal-Wright: Numerical Optimization](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1428830653259556280&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5).

I haven't tried Knitro recently.

[Ipopt](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt) is the most robust solver among those I have tried, I highly recommend it. It implements the line search method and is written in C++.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what "reflective" adds to the "trust region" definition. However, [Knitro](http://www.ziena.com/knitro.html) is a powerful trust-region interior-point optimizer with a C/C++ interface. Unfortunately, *Knitro* is only available without cost in a limited edition for students; the full version requires a commercial license.

There is also [Ipopt](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt), which is *not* trust-region but nevertheless a powerful C/C++ based large-scale nonlinear constrained optimization engine with an open-source license.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried checking if your function is convex, if LM and some other convex optimization algorithm converge differently, there is a good chance that the base function is not convex. Also have you checked if the cost function is at least of order 2. If this is the case minimizing the square of the cost function can be better than minimizing the cost function alone.